# Laravel old() directive with conditional default value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8, and have several input fields which of course has an old() directive on every value="" tag.

This is my example right now:

```
<input class="form-control input-md" name="contact_name" type="text" value="@if($edit){{ $ad->contact_name }}@else{{ old('contact_name')}}@endif">
```

I now that if I use this: `{{ old('contact_name', "John")}}`

The default value will be "John"

But I want to do a check if there is a user logged in and prefill that input with the User contact name.

My idea is something like this:

```
value="@if($edit){{ $ad->contact_name }}@else{{ old('contact_name', Auth::user()->name)}}@endif
```

And it works! But of course, it throws: `Trying to get property 'name'` when I get an incognito window.

So, how do I evaluate logged in users and prefill this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-optional) helper:

```php
{{ old('contact_name', optional(Auth::user())->name) }}
```

Comment: Oh men, what a pretty solution. I didn't remember the optional helper.

Solved as this ugly: old('contact_name', isset(Auth::user()->name) ? Auth::user()->name : '')

But yours are way more pretty Thanks!